# rabbitmq cluster mistmatch hostname issue

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, openstack

I have deployed `openstack-ansible` with 3 node rabbitmq cluster and it use lxc to run rabbitmq on top, I am seeing very strange error here when i did `rabbitmqctl status` command, if you notice its talking to wrong node `ostack-controller-01` is host node and not a actual rabbitmq node..

```
[root@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2 ~]# rabbitmqctl status
Status of node 'rabbit@ostack-controller-01' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@ostack-controller-01': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@ostack-controller-01']

rabbit@ostack-controller-01:
  * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on ostack-controller-01: address (cannot connect to host/port)

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-06@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: SssFdXBI7wTevePuCt5d9w==
```

How do i fix this behavior and tell rabbitmq to talk to correct host which is `ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2`

I have tried `forget_cluster_node` but no luck, still throwing same error.

```
[root@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2 ~]# rabbitmqctl forget_cluster_node rabbit@ostack-controller-01
Removing node 'rabbit@ostack-controller-01' from cluster ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@ostack-controller-01': nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@ostack-controller-01']

rabbit@ostack-controller-01:
  * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on ostack-controller-01: address (cannot connect to host/port)


current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-39@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: SssFdXBI7wTevePuCt5d9w==
```

## UPDATE: 1

```
[root@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2 rabbitmq]# rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2 status
Status of node 'rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2' ...
[{pid,8720},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.9"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.9"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.6.9"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.9"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.9"},
      {rabbit_common,
          "Modules shared by rabbitmq-server and rabbitmq-erlang-client",
          "3.6.9"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.14"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4.2"},
      {cowboy,"Small, fast, modular HTTP server.","1.0.4"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.3.0"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","8.1.3.1.1"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.4"},
      {cowlib,"Support library for manipulating Web protocols.","1.0.2"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","3.7.4"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","6.3.9"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","7.0.4.1"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 4.0.4","4.0.4"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","2.1.1"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.14.3.1"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","3.0.3"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.3"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.2.0.1"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3.5.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:6:6] [async-threads:128] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,64189296},
      {connection_readers,179280},
      {connection_writers,26568},
      {connection_channels,124504},
      {connection_other,127440},
      {queue_procs,2832},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,406280},
      {other_proc,21056136},
      {mnesia,500680},
      {metrics,205984},
      {mgmt_db,127256},
      {msg_index,47416},
      {other_ets,2692192},
      {binary,1591656},
      {code,24765630},
      {atom,1033401},
      {other_system,11505193}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,
     [{clustering,25672,"::"},
      {amqp,5672,"::"},
      {'amqp/ssl',5671,"::"},
      {http,15672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,6662953369},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,82822516736},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,65436},
      {total_used,5},
      {sockets_limit,58890},
      {sockets_used,3}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,376}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,14},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

## UPDATE - 2

This is interesting... why following command working but not `rabbitmqctl cluster_status`?

```
[root@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2 rabbitmq]# rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2 cluster_status
Cluster status of node 'rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2' ...
[{nodes,
     [{disc,
          ['rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2',
           'rabbit@ostack-controller-02-rabbit-mq-container-d510bdfc',
           'rabbit@ostack-controller-03-rabbit-mq-container-c482ee13']}]},
 {running_nodes,
     ['rabbit@ostack-controller-02-rabbit-mq-container-d510bdfc',
      'rabbit@ostack-controller-03-rabbit-mq-container-c482ee13',
      'rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2']},
 {cluster_name,<<"openstack">>},
 {partitions,
     [{'rabbit@ostack-controller-02-rabbit-mq-container-d510bdfc',
          ['rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2',
           'rabbit@ostack-controller-03-rabbit-mq-container-c482ee13']},
      {'rabbit@ostack-controller-03-rabbit-mq-container-c482ee13',
          ['rabbit@ostack-controller-02-rabbit-mq-container-d510bdfc']}]},
 {alarms,
     [{'rabbit@ostack-controller-02-rabbit-mq-container-d510bdfc',[]},
      {'rabbit@ostack-controller-03-rabbit-mq-container-c482ee13',[]},
      {'rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2',[]}]}]
```

Comment: What is the output of `rabbitmqctl -n rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2 status`?

Comment: I have updated my question with your query..

Comment: What is the output of `hostname` , `hostname -f` and `echo $HOSTNAME`?

Comment: `ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2.openstack.local`

Comment: One more, `echo $HOSTNAME`

Comment: oh!! ech $HOSTNAME -> `ostack-controller-01.foo.example.com`

Comment: I did `export HOSTNAME=ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2` and now it fixed :)  sweet!!!  Please can you post this stuff in answer section i would like to give you `++++++++`

Comment: I've provided an answer with a better alternative.

Comment: This is lxc behavior it carries host `env` to container when using `lxc-attach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, RabbitMQ 3.6.9 is old and you should be using the latest version.

Having said that, that's not the issue. The output of `echo $HOSTNAME` is this:

```
ostack-controller-01.foo.example.com
```

So, when `rabbitmqctl status` runs, it uses [this code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/rabbitmq_v3_6_9/scripts/rabbitmq-env#L114-L116) to determine the node name to which to connect to. Since the `HOSTNAME` variable is set, that is used to determine the node name, and `rabbitmqctl` tries to use `rabbit@ostack-controller-01`, which fails.

You can continue to use the `-n rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2` argument to `rabbitmqctl` to work around this. Or, you can create the `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` file with this content:

```
NODENAME=rabbit@ostack-controller-01-rabbit-mq-container-1bf6ede2
```

Then, `rabbitmqctl status` and other `rabbitmqctl` commands should work. You would then repeat this process on every node, using that node's correct name in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`